Eating liver to become immortal
I'm trying to find a movie a saw on SBS here in Australia back in the late 90's or early 2000's. 
It's an Asian action film, possibly Chinese or Korean.
The movie starts with two badly wounded men on some temple steps. When one of the men wake up inside the temple some hours later he is told by a third man that his friend is dead, and that the only way in which his own life could be saved was if he ate the liver of his friend, which has now made him immortal just like the third man. I think this scene takes place several hundred years ago.
The final scene of the movie, which is set relatively current, is of the third man and the survivor battling it out with a sword and machine gun.

That's it. That's the one. Perfect. Thanks!

Sounds like Aragami from 2003. From Wiki:

Two seriously wounded samurai find refuge from a storm at an isolated temple, the home of a swordsman and a mysterious young woman. One samurai awakes to find that not only has his comrade died, but that his wounds have miraculously healed. He discovers that he has been given the power of immortality by the swordsman, a man once known as the legendary Miyamoto Musashi, who now lives an endless existence as Aragami, a "god of battle".

He survives by eating his friend's liver, and the movie ends just before a battle between a sword and an automatic weapon. I already supplied this answer here, but your question is different. The trailer:



